# How do get result value from stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Please help me, I created this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[objueb]
    @UebKat varchar(500) = NULL,
    @Multikz nchar(1) = "|",
    @Objekte nchar(999) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        St2.Ueberk, 
        substring((SELECT @Multikz + ST1.ObjektId AS [text()]
                   FROM dbo.DtaVor ST1
                   WHERE ST1.Ueberk = ST2.Ueberk
                   ORDER BY ST1.Ueberk
                   FOR XML PATH ('') ), 2, 1000) [Objekte] 
    FROM
        dbo.DtaVor ST2 
    WHERE
        Ueberk = @Uebkat
END
```

The result is :

```
|----------------|---------------------------------------------|
|  Ueberk        | Objekte                                     |
|----------------|---------------------------------------------|
|   BLX HS       | 10002533  |10001132  |10001560  |10002156   |
|----------------|---------------------------------------------|
```

The result is always one row.

I'd like to receive the result of 'Objekte' in a parameter (`@Objekte`)

Thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Stored procedures are **highly** vendor-specific ! Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming DBMS is SQL Server based on use of `FOR XML PATH`. You just need to assign the result to the variable:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[objueb]
@UebKat varchar(500) = NULL,
@Multikz nchar(1) = "|",
@Objekte nchar(999) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @Objekte = Objekte
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
    St2.Ueberk, 
    substring((SELECT @Multikz + ST1.ObjektId AS [text()]
               FROM dbo.DtaVor ST1
               WHERE ST1.Ueberk = ST2.Ueberk
               ORDER BY ST1.Ueberk
               FOR XML PATH ('') ), 2, 1000) AS [Objekte] 
    FROM
        dbo.DtaVor ST2 
    WHERE
        Ueberk = @Uebkat) o
END
```

Is the `DISTINCT` necessary to ensure one row (is `Ueberk` a primary key?)? If not you can remove the sub-select:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[objueb]
@UebKat varchar(500) = NULL,
@Multikz nchar(1) = "|",
@Objekte nchar(999) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  
    @Objekte = substring((SELECT @Multikz + ST1.ObjektId AS [text()]
               FROM dbo.DtaVor ST1
               WHERE ST1.Ueberk = ST2.Ueberk
               ORDER BY ST1.Ueberk
               FOR XML PATH ('') ), 2, 1000)
    FROM
        dbo.DtaVor ST2 
    WHERE
        Ueberk = @Uebkat
END
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot!!